# Extjs Grid scroll dons't work after application running while

Tags: extjs, gridpanel, scrollbars

I am developing an application using Extjs.

In the application, I has a grid on the viewport. For reasons, I need to add record to the grid very often(maybe few times per second).  When the grid store has more than 150 records, the store removes first record and then add a new record bottom. So grid store contains 150 record maximum.

My problem: 
Scroll bar for the grid panel works in the begin, but doesn't work after the application running while.

Do any one have any idea or solution for the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is the code to insert record to store                       function insertItems(store, records) {
        store.add(records);
        if (store.count() > 150) store.removeAt(0);
}                                                                            After above function has been called many times, grid scroll bar doesn't work. (grid is grid panel which own the store)

Comment: I think we would need more code than that. Preferably we would also need the html and styles that are used. For clarity: Edit you question and insert the code into the question.

Comment: Try my solution on this post:

[stackoverflow - extjs scroll's grid stop working][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426906/extjs-scrolls-grid-stop-working/16435311#16435311

Comment: is answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your version of ExtJS to 4.1.2 or above. The virtual strollers in 4.0.7 had these issues.