# extjs scroll's grid stop working

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I´ve spent a couple of days dealing with an issue about grids' vertical scroll. Scrolls just stop working under some unknown conditions, I mean, it is not deterministic I think.

My application has lots of grids and most of them work perfectly always but just a couple of them just don´t.

I found this [Extjs Grid scroll dons't work after application running while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213740/extjs-grid-scroll-donst-work-after-application-running-while) that describes the same problem that I have currently, however a migration to a newer version is not the solution for me because after do it (yes, I did it but rolled it back) I found more problems that it is risky enough to discard given the applications is going to production in a few days.

Does someone have a solution, patch, hack or whatever to workaround this problem?

We are using extjs 4.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with scrolling is localized to 4.0.x-4.0.7 releases due to Sencha's attempt to use virtual scrolling technique. 
As you have discovered this strategy backfired and has since been reverted to native scrolling.

Your issue is solvable by upgrading to 4.1+ release.

Comment: I know what the problem is and also know the solution you say, however upgrade is not an option in this case. I also tried reconfiguring the grid with no luck. Thanks for you help, @dbrin

Answer (score 0):

Try to using:

```
 grid.reconfigure(store,null);
```

Where:

- grid: Grid that is modify.
- Store: it's the original store.
- null: value for 'new' columns.

See the comment too: [reconfigure function on Sencha Api 4.0.7](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-method-reconfigure)